# Replacing NaN with regression estimates containing lagged Y value

Tags: python, nan, statsmodels

I have a dataframe of monthly data:

[image]

I need to forecast (i.e. overwrite NaN) highlighted in yellow by month using the following linear regression:

pkg_yld = C + adv + pkg_yld(1)

where pkg_yld(1) is the lagged value of pkg_yld from the previous month.

Here is the estimated model:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = df.loc['2020-06-30':'2021-06-30','adv']
y = df.loc['2020-06-30':'2021-06-30','pkg_yld']

X = sm.add_constant(X)                        # X var:  ADV plus the constant term
X['pkg_yld_lag']=df_un['pkg_yld'].shift(1)    # X var: pkg_yld lagged 1 month

model = sm.OLS(y, X, missing='drop').fit()       # Y var, X var(s) + constant term 
model.summary()
```

and the summary output:

[image]

So the formula is:
2.813178 + 0.000009 x ADV + 0.650444 x pkg_yld_lag

For July 2021: use the provided July ADV value plus the **actual recorded June pkg_yld value**:
2.8113178 + 0.000009*(16101.75) + 0.650444*(8.28) = 8.34

For Aug 2021: use the provided August 2021 ADV value plus the **predicted July pkg_yld as the lag value**:
2.8113178 + 0.000009*(13865.25) + 0.650444*(8.34) = 8.37

and so on.

**The first month of forecast always uses the last recorded pkg_yld value and thereafter uses the predicted pkg_yld value from the model.** Model.predict does not work given the presence of the lagged Y value.

How would I proceed to end up with the final result below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

With the help of a colleague the solution to generating the above results can be achieved using a loop to predict the next 6 months and then put those numbers into the existing dataframe:

```
counter = 0
while counter < 6:
 
    df['pkg_yld_lag']=df['pkg_yld'].shift(1)                  # Create a 1-month lag of pkg_yld
    adv_input = sm.add_constant(df[['adv','pkg_yld_lag']])    # Set up model model 
    df['pkg_yld_p']= model.predict(adv_input)                 # Predict 
    df['pkg_yld'].fillna(df["pkg_yld_p"], inplace=True)       # Replace NaN with predicted value

    counter += 1
```

Then drop the unneeded columns:

```
df.drop(['pkg_yld_lag','pkg_yld_p'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

End result:

[image]